# SQL Use MAX or TOP to get one row of each result only

Tags: sql, get, row

I have a db with 3 tables:

- **Users**       UserID, Username
- **Computers**   ComputerID, ComputerName
- **Logons**      LogonDate, UserID, ComputerID

I am using the following query to try to get just the latest Username and LogonDate for each computer.

```
SELECT MAX(LogonDate) AS LogonDate, ComputerName, Username 
FROM Users u, Computers c, Logons l 
WHERE u.UserID = l.UserID 
  AND c.ComputerID = l.ComputerID 
GROUP BY ComputerName, Username 
ORDER BY ComputerName
```

Understandably, it presents the latest logon for *each* user. I'd like to limit it to just the latest entry.

Help please :)
Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT (select MAX(l.LogonDate) from users z where z.UserID = u.UserId) AS LogonDate, c.ComputerName, u.Username 
FROM Users u, Computers c, Logons l 
WHERE u.UserID = l.UserID AND c.ComputerID = l.ComputerID
GROUP BY c.ComputerName, u.Username
ORDER BY c.ComputerName
```

Answer (score 0):

First, learn proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  So the basic query is:

```
SELECT l.LogonDate, c.ComputerName, u.Username
FROM Logons l JOIN
     Users u
     ON u.UserID = l.UserID JOIN
     Computers c
     ON c.ComputerID = l.ComputerID;
```

To get the most recent logon, use `row_number()` or a condition like this:

```
SELECT l.LogonDate, c.ComputerName, u.Username
FROM Logons l JOIN
     Users u
     ON u.UserID = l.UserID JOIN
     Computers c
     ON c.ComputerID = l.ComputerID
WHERE l.LogonDate = (SELECT MAX(l2.LogonDate)
                     FROM Logons l2
                     WHERE l2.ComputerID = l.ComputerID
                    );
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm not a dba, just know enough to get myself tied up in knots. I will try to mend my ways. :)